# import error in eclipse

Tags: node.js, eclipse, git, msvcr100.dll

An error has occurred in Eclipse.

When I import a `Nodejs` project(by existing projects into workspace), `BEX64` error happens.

When I update code from git (I mean 'pull' function of node project like 'update to version' or 'update to head' in SVN), `BEX64` error happens too.

I use Windows 7 enterprise K 64bit.

I already have `msvcr100.dll` file in `System32` and `SysWOW64` folder.

How can i solve this problem?

please check the message below.

```
Problem signature:

Problem Event Name: BEX64

Application Name:   eclipse.exe

Application Version:    0.0.0.0

Application Timestamp:  553e7d2c

Fault Module Name:  MSVCR100.dll

Fault Module Version:   10.0.40219.1

Fault Module Timestamp: 4d5f034a

Exception Offset:   0000000000070468

Exception Code: c0000417

Exception Data: 0000000000000000

OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.4

Locale ID:  1042
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking Nodeclipse project http://www.nodeclipse.org/
There many ways to import a project, e.g. as General project, but there want be any JS- related functions.

Current recommendation http://www.nodeclipse.org/usage is run Nodeclipse CLI tool  https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodeclipse
 `nodeclipse -p` to prepare for import, than import as existing project